# Sharing data across 2 classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I have to share a `String[]` across two classes. One class sets the array and the other gets the array. I made four classes. One contains the Array at superclass level and the array is accessed in the subclasses. And one class holds `main()`
here they are.

`ApplicationDataPool.java`

```
public class ApplicationDataPool extends JFrame {
    String[] thisContact;

    public ApplicationDataPool() {
        super("Update Record");
    }

    public String[] getThisContact() {
        return thisContact;
    }

    public void setThisContact(String[] thisContact) {
        this.thisContact = thisContact;
    }


}
```

`UpdateProcessStepOneFrame.java`

```
public class UpdateProcessStepOneFrame extends ApplicationDataPool {

        public UpdateProcessStepOneFrame() {
            String[] something = { "fname", "lname" };
            setThisContact(something);
            UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame step2 = new UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame();
            step2.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

`UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame.java`

```
public class UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame extends ApplicationDataPool{

    public UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame(){
    String[] theContact = getThisContact();
    //Here is the problem        
    //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
      System.out.println(theContact.length);
    }

}
```

**PROBLEM: whenever I access the array anywhere Java throws a `NullPointerException`. Why is this happening. How do I rectify it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `thisContact` variable is *owned* by the instance of `UpdateProcessStepOneFrame` or `UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame` you've created. If you want to share `thisContact` between all instances of `ApplicationDataPool` you have to defined it as `static`. Which means the variable will be *owned* by the class and not by its instances.

```
protected static String[] thisContact;
```

Comment: Really simple and adds to my understanding of sharing data across classes. Thank You.

Comment: Same thing i told you as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The classes `UpdateProcessStepOneFrame` and `UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame` don't know about each other so you need to do `setThisContact(something)` in the `UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame` class in order for `getThisContact` to not be null.

Answer (score 0):

there are two different classes...so String[] theContact will be null in second class unless you set it...

Comment: theContact is not static to be shared between instances of the same classs

Answer (score 0):

The first call to

```
  setThisContact(something);
```

sets the sets the array for the UpdateProcessStepOneFrame object (via the base class).

Then when you execute this:

```
 UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame step2 = new UpdateProcessStepTwoFrame();
```

you're creating a new object with its own separate array, which is never initialised and hence throws a NPE on theContact.length